# Is the quotient of connected linear algebraic groups connected?

Tags: group-theory, connectedness

Let $K$ be a field (of characteristic zero if it makes things nicer) and $G/K$ a *connected* linear algebraic group (i.e. smooth affine). Let $N \leq G$ be a *connected* normal linear $K$-subgroup of $G$.

> Is $G/N$ connected?

Intuitively this should be true, but I can't prove it.
EDIT: I forgot that the quotient of a connected topological space is connected. This should settle the question.